# User-Function Runs But Doesn't display value

Tags: vba, ms-access, user-defined-functions

I've written a VBA UDF to calculate an AQL Sample Size by the Inspection Level (IL Variable in my code), and Lot size (Batch Variable in my code).

In an Access userform, I have the values for my two variables displayed in a text box. I have a third text box which has my UDF, that I want to auto-update to the new value when I add or change either of the two variables. It never changes from zero.

When I update either variable, if I put a stop in the UDF VBA code, the code does run, and provides the correct answer in a Watch in my VBE as I step through.

Also, somewhat related question, I'm guessing you cannot use a UDF in a table? I can use the same UDF in an Excel table, so I was thinking I should be able to.

```vb
Public Function SampleSize(IL As String, Batch As Long) As Long
If IL = "S1" Then
    Select Case Batch
    Case 2 To 50
        Sample = 2
    Case 51 To 500
        Sample = 3
    Case 501 To 35000
        Sample = 5
    Case Is >= 35001
        Sample = 8
    End Select
End If

If IL = "S2" Then
Select Case Batch
    Case 2 To 25
        Sample = 2
    Case 26 To 150
        Sample = 3
    Case 151 To 1200
        Sample = 5
    Case 1201 To 35000
        Sample = 8
    Case Is >= 35001
        Sample = 13
End Select
End If

If IL = "S3" Then
Select Case Batch
    Case 2 To 15
        Sample = 2
    Case 16 To 50
        Sample = 3
    Case 51 To 150
        Sample = 5
    Case 151 To 500
        Sample = 8
    Case 501 To 3200
        Sample = 13
    Case 3201 To 35000
        Sample = 20
    Case 35001 To 500000
        Sample = 32
    Case Is >= 500001
        Sample = 50
End Select
End If

If IL = "S4" Then
Select Case Batch
    Case 2 To 15
        Sample = 2
    Case 16 To 25
        Sample = 3
    Case 26 To 90
        Sample = 5
    Case 91 To 150
        Sample = 8
    Case 151 To 500
        Sample = 13
    Case 501 To 1200
        Sample = 20
    Case 1201 To 10000
        Sample = 32
    Case 10001 To 35000
        Sample = 50
    Case 35001 To 500000
        Sample = 80
    Case Is >= 500001
        Sample = 125
End Select
End If

If IL = "G1" Then
Select Case Batch
    Case 2 To 15
        Sample = 2
    Case 16 To 25
        Sample = 3
    Case 26 To 90
        Sample = 5
    Case 91 To 150
        Sample = 8
    Case 151 To 280
        Sample = 13
    Case 281 To 500
        Sample = 20
    Case 501 To 1200
        Sample = 32
    Case 1201 To 3200
        Sample = 50
    Case 3201 To 10000
        Sample = 80
    Case 10001 To 35000
        Sample = 125
    Case 35001 To 150000
        Sample = 200
    Case 150001 To 500000
        Sample = 315
    Case Is >= 500001
        Sample = 500
End Select
End If

If IL = "G2" Then
Select Case Batch
    Case 2 To 8
        Sample = 2
    Case 9 To 15
        Sample = 3
    Case 16 To 25
        Sample = 5
    Case 26 To 50
        Sample = 8
    Case 51 To 90
        Sample = 13
    Case 91 To 150
        Sample = 20
    Case 151 To 280
        Sample = 32
    Case 281 To 500
        Sample = 50
    Case 501 To 1200
        Sample = 80
    Case 1201 To 3200
        Sample = 125
    Case 3201 To 10000
        Sample = 200
    Case 10001 To 35000
        Sample = 315
    Case 35001 To 150000
        Sample = 500
    Case 150001 To 500000
        Sample = 800
    Case Is >= 500001
        Sample = 1250
End Select
End If

If IL = "G3" Then
Select Case Batch
    Case 2 To 8
        Sample = 3
    Case 9 To 15
        Sample = 5
    Case 16 To 25
        Sample = 8
    Case 26 To 50
        Sample = 13
    Case 51 To 90
        Sample = 20
    Case 91 To 150
        Sample = 32
    Case 151 To 280
        Sample = 50
    Case 281 To 500
        Sample = 80
    Case 501 To 1200
        Sample = 125
    Case 1201 To 3200
        Sample = 200
    Case 3201 To 10000
        Sample = 315
    Case 10001 To 35000
        Sample = 500
    Case 35001 To 150000
        Sample = 800
    Case 150001 To 500000
        Sample = 1250
    Case Is >= 500001
        Sample = 2000
End Select
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign a return value to the function itself!

You should place this line of code as indicated:

```
    SampleSize = Sample
End Function
```

Also it is good practice to declare variables within the scope of your function.

```
Dim Sample As Long
```

When declared it will be initialized to 0, which will also be your default return value and the same Type as your Function.

Undeclared variables will be Variant type and initialized to Empty...

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I would like to use my function in my table, but it appears I can't. Like, I want to treat my table just like an excel table, write a formula using my UDF, then have it calculate in the table. Am I correct?

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you mean by "use my function in my table", but referencing data in Excel is entirely differently than in Access.  Possibly you can create a "Range" in your Excel worksheet, then you can reference the range using SQL like methods...

Comment: In my Access Table, I'd like to have one field have a formula based on my UDF, so when I type in two other fields, that field does the calculation, similar to Excel where I might have data in cell A1, and Cell A2, and then a Formula in A3 that updates as I make changes to A1 and A2.